# Mysql LEFT Join query only returns one row when adding Count() mysql function

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I have this mysql query (evolving **two tables**: `Users` and `Files`) that's giving me headaches:

```
SELECT Users.GUID, Users.Name, Users.CreationDate, Files.Date, 
    Count(Files.GUID) As FilesCount
FROM Users

    LEFT JOIN Files ON Users.GUID = Files.UserGUID

WHERE Users.Group =  '1'
```

When I execute it, it **always** return 1 row (which is not what I want). But if I remove this:

```
Count(Files.Date) As FilesCount
```

It correctly return all the rows that I expect.

**I basically need to get the number of files that belongs to a user** (along with the user info)

**My question is:** How can I fix this & make the mysql query return the user basic info along with the files count?

BTW, I'm using CodeIgniter 2 with PHP 5 (although I don't think it matters here...)

Comment: Try to add `Group By (Users.GUID)` after Where clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `COUNT()` aggregate will return only one row in absence of a `GROUP BY` clause, and MySQL is lenient about the presence or contents of the `GROUP BY` (your query would have failed with a syntax error in most other RDBMS).

Since you have multiple columns, you ought to join against a subquery to get the count per `Files.GUID`.  Although MySQL will permit you to `GROUP BY Users.GUID` without the subquery, which is simpler, you may not get the results you expect from `Users.Name` or `Users.CreationDate`. This method is more portable:

```
SELECT
  Users.GUID,
  Users.Name,
  Users.CreationDate,
  FileCount
FROM
  Users
  /* Subquery returns UserGUID and associated file count */
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT UserGUID, COUNT(*) AS FileCount
    FROM Files
    GROUP BY UserGUID
  ) fc ON Users.GUID = fc.UserGuid
WHERE Users.Group = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by user, otherwise it collapses all to one row: `GROUP BY Users.GUID`

Answer (score 2):

This query has subquery which separately calculate the total `Count` of files for each `GUID`.

```
SELECT  Users.GUID, 
        Users.Name, 
        Users.CreationDate, 
        Files.Date, 
        c.FilesCount
FROM    Users
        LEFT JOIN Files 
            ON Users.GUID = Files.UserGUID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT UserGUID, Count(GUID) As FilesCount
            FROM Files
            GROUP BY UserGUID
        ) c on c.UserGUID = Users.GUID
-- WHERE Users.Group =  '1'
```